# How to retrieve reference to AWS::S3::MultipartUpload with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, multipartform-data

I have a rails app and in a controller action I am able to create a multipart upload like so:

```
  def create
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    bucket = s3.buckets["my_bucket"]
    key = "some_new_file_name.ext"
    obj = bucket.objects[key]
    mpu = obj.multipart_upload
    render json: {
      :id => mpu.id
    }
  end
```

so now the client has the multipart upload id and she can upload parts to aws with her browser.  I wish to create another action which will assemble the parts once they are done uploading.  Something like:

```
  def assemble
    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    bucket = s3.buckets["my_bucket"]
    key = params['key']
    bucket.objects[key].multipart_upload.complete
    render json: { :status => "all good" }
  end
```

This isn't working though.  How do I retrieve a reference to the multipartUpload object or create a new one with the key or id so that I can call the "complete" method on it?  Any insight is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I found this method in the documentation for the Client class and got it to work as follows:

```
client = AWS::S3::Client.new

# reassemble partsList
partsList = []
params[:partsList].each do |key, pair|
  partsList.push pair
end

options = {
  :bucket_name => 'my_bucket',
  :key => params[:key],
  :upload_id => params[:upload_id],
  :parts => partsList
}
client.complete_multipart_upload(options)
```